# flutter_downloader auto open file when complete

Tags: flutter, flutter-downloader

so I'm trying to work with download manager in flutter using flutter_downloader package. I manage to make my app download the file I wanted. How can I make my app more advance ? I wanted my app to be able to open the downloaded file automatically when the download is done.

Another question is, if I already download the file first time how can I make the button trigger to open the file location rather than downloading the file again ?

Here's my current code:

```
  TextButton(
    child: Text(
      ticketData['file_attachment_map'][index]['name'],
      style: primaryColor600Style.copyWith(fontSize:14.sp),
    ),
    
    onPressed: () async {
      final permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.request();
    
      if (permissionStatus.isGranted) {
      final externalDir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    
      final taskId =await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: ticketData['file_attachment_map']
        [index]['url'],
        savedDir:externalDir!.path,
        showNotification:true,
        openFileFromNotification:true,
        );
      } else {
        print('Permission denied');
      }
    },
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [open_file](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file) package after downloaded

```
if(taskId != null){
    await OpenFile.open(filePath);
  }
}
```

And you can check file exist before download file

```
import 'dart:io';
File("path/to/file").exists()
```

Comment: can I use the file("path/to/file").exists(); in if else statement ?

Comment: var isExist = await File("path/to/file").exists();
if(isExitst){ show button open } else { download }

Comment: so I need to change "path/to/file", into my saved path and the file name right ? 

example:
FIle(externalDir!.path/to/ticketData['file_attachment_map'][index]['name']).exists()

Comment: yes, you can try, just you pathFile is alway right

Answer (score 0):

As a complement to @Xuann Thucc answer, you can use the [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) which is a fork of *open_file* but is better maintained and fixes many issues with the original lib.

```dart
import 'package:open_filex/open_filex.dart';

// in async function
await OpenFilex.open(filePath);
```